# Testcafe is not reporting to slack when working on a container

Tags: docker, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I started running my E2E test on azure cointainer instances.

The code is reporting to my slack channel without any issue when working on local but for some reason it wont send any report to slack when running in the container.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:edge

RUN apk --no-cache --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/ add \
 nodejs nodejs-npm chromium firefox xwininfo xvfb dbus eudev ttf-freefont fluxbox

COPY . /opt/testcafe

RUN cd /opt/testcafe; \
 npm install && \
 npm cache clean --force && \
 rm -rf /tmp/* && \
 chmod +x /opt/testcafe/testcafe-docker.sh && \
 adduser -D user

USER root
EXPOSE 1337 1338
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/testcafe/testcafe-docker.sh"]
```

Entrypoint:

```
#!/bin/sh
### This file need to be saved as Linux File (FL) ###
XVFB_SCREEN_WIDTH=${SCREEN_WIDTH-1920}
XVFB_SCREEN_HEIGHT=${SCREEN_HEIGHT-1080}

dbus-daemon --session --fork
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 "${XVFB_SCREEN_WIDTH}x${XVFB_SCREEN_HEIGHT}x24" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
export DISPLAY=:1.0
fluxbox >/dev/null 2>&1 &
if [ -d "/opt/testcafe/src/tests/$TESTS" ]
then
    node /opt/testcafe/node_modules/testcafe/bin/testcafe-with-v8-flag-filter.js --ports 1337,1338 '"'"$BROWSER"'" --no-sandbox' -c 4 --url=$URL --reporter slack --skip-js-errors /opt/testcafe/src/tests/$TESTS
else
    node /opt/testcafe/node_modules/testcafe/bin/testcafe-with-v8-flag-filter.js --ports 1337,1338 '"'"$BROWSER"'" --no-sandbox"' -c 4 --url=$URL --reporter slack --skip-js-errors /opt/testcafe/src/tests
fi
```

my dependencies in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
        "luxon": "^1.22.0",
        "mailosaur": "^6.0.4",
        "minimist": "^1.2.5",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "request": "^2.88.2",
        "request-promise-native": "^1.0.8",
        "testcafe-reporter-slack": "0.0.6",
        "testcafe-reporter-teamcity": "1.0.10"
    }
```

Anyone faced this issue?

Comment: What if you use another reporter? Is `testcafe-reporter-slack` the only one that doesn't work?

Comment: Found the issue. Basically you need to be on the root directory where .env of the slack reporter is. I just did a CD /otp/testcafe and fixed this issue.